# Dealing with Duplicate Method Headers

Tags: java, methods, parameters, conventions

I'm new(ish) to coding, so let's get that out of the way. Also, I'm currently using Java.
I want to instantiate a Line object in two different ways:

`public Line(double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2){}//creates a line connecting two points` and

`public Line(double x, double y, double dir, double length){}//creates a line extending off of one point`

However, they both have the same method header according to the compiler.

I considered adding a useless parameter to the second constructor, but that seems messy and unnecessary. Does anyone have any suggestions on how to deal with a problem like this one both now and in the future?

Note: This topic is only about fixing the header, not about how my code could be improved. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create two different static factory method for both of those constructors calls.
According to Wikipedia :

> The Factory Method design pattern is one of the "Gang of Four"
> design patterns that describe how to solve recurring design problems
> to design flexible and reusable object-oriented software, that is,
> objects that are easier to implement, change, test, and reuse.
>
> The Factory Method design pattern is used instead of the regular class
> constructor for keeping within the SOLID principles of programming,
> decoupling the construction of objects from the objects themselves

Factory methods are just essentially methods that can have different names (and not having to use the name of the class) and a different number of parameters or even the same number of parameters with a previous one. You can do something like this :

```
public static Line createJoining(double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2){...}
public static Line createExtending(double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2){...}
```

Then you could have a single constructor like this

```
public Line(double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2){}//creates a line connecting two points
```

Inside **createJoining()** and **createExtending()**, you could call this constructor,
and put your different program logic inside these two factory methods.

**createJoining()** and **createExtending()**, would have to return a new instance of **Line** like this:

```
public static Line createJoining(double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2){
  // program logic goes here, where you can do some calculations

   return new Line(x1, y1, x2, y2);
}

public static Line createExtending(double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2){
// program logic goes here, where you can do some calculations

   return new Line(x1, y1, x2, y2);
}
```

Usage example,

```
Line joinedLine = Line.createJoining(0.1, 3.5, 10.5, 1.0);
Line extendedLine = Line.createExtended(0.6, 29.4, 20.0, 2.0);
```

[More info about Factory Methods here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern)

Comment: Thanks, this was very helpful! Just wanted to clarify: the idea of the factory method is that I would instantiate the object with a constructor just to put it into memory, then call a factory method afterword to tailor the fields?

Comment: When you need an object of your class **Line**, you would use **createJoining()** and **createExtending()** factory methods and not the constructor itself, because the factory methods would do the work of the constructor somehow. You might even need to make your constructor **private** so no one can use it, other than **Line**

Comment: @TheeElm if my answer was helpful, you can upvote it. If it solves your problem :)

Comment: After testing, there seems to be one issue with these methods: I am using polymorphism to group several different shapes (Line, Rectangle) under one label. However, this makes the factory methods for each separate shape not work. Any ideas? Thanks for the help btw :)

Comment: Sorry, @TheeElm I couldn't understand what you were trying to do there. Maybe uploading your code might be better.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply—I originally thought that factory methods were non-static, and that you called them after you instantiated the object. I got it working now. Thanks!

Comment: @TheeElm  Yeah, no problem. But I also updated my answer indicating that the factory methods were static.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to avoid *the same method header* and at the same time use more meaningful parameter types:

```
import java.awt.geom.Point2D;
…
        public Line(Point2D.Double p1, Point2D.Double p2) { … }

        public Line(Point2D.Double p, double dir, double length) { … }
```

Comment: I am actually making classes that provide additional functions to each of the java.awt.geom Shapes. This would work as well—I will probably add this parameter set in the future for additional options when constructing a Line. Thanks for the feedback!